# Best way to keep track of application's activities started and finishing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-lifecycle

i am stuck on something and really appreciate some help regarding a logical question please,

I have an application and in that i need to keep track of my activities when started and finished. Here is some logic i am trying to code for or get a solution. 
For ex

1. My MainActivity opens.
2. Then when i navigate to other activities, i can keep track of when these activities 
   are started and finished. I increment/decrement a `value` here just to keep a count.
3. After doing its purpose user comes back to the MainActivity and i as a dev would be aware since the `value` would be zero of the default one at the start, so i can run some code before the app actually exits.

I am trying to comply with android activity lifecycle to avoid any false positives. Is the apps ApplicationActivity the way to do it? Sorry if its a simple question i am not experienced and needed some fellow developers help.

Thanks for your time.

*Update--

I have multiple apps which use the same hardware resource, in order for no mix ups i wanted to release the access as i switch from one app (A -> B) to another with regards to activities. Reason is that currently if multiple activities from app A or B request access the hardware it messes it up and doesn't show the required output. So i was thinking maybe i keep a numerical track of the activities.

Comment: Normally you don't need to keep track of any of this, why do you want to do this?

Comment: There're more than one ways of doing this. There's certainly lifecycle callback that you can use and there are other various architectural ways of doing this too. However, to achieve a right solution it will help if you state your requirements more specifically here.

Comment: @m0skit0 updated question, thanks.

Comment: @codeFood updated question, thanks.

Comment: Ok I see, now it makes sense. Don't do that. I've been in your situation and tried to do it that way. You will get a lot of concurrency problems between the apps and hard to debug bugs. The best way to do it is to have a Service that actually controls that hardware and exposes an API to the hardware to the apps. This way the Service can control the calls to the hardware. I did this through a ContentProvider but AIDL should work as well.

Comment: You do have a specific case and @m0skit0 puts forward a fair point on concurrency headache. I'm inclined towards saying that the suggested approach is good. Its worth giving a go. The standard android constructs, such as lifecycle callbacks etc are mostly make to work within the constraints of a particular app.

Comment: Note that this might seem too much work compared to a simple global variable to control that, but in my experience you will only get concurrency headaches and memory leaks. Or maybe I just implemented it wrong :)